# How to trigger scroll on spesific element or div?

Tags: jquery

I have some code that allows me to check my position on site, and then allows me to do somthing..example to show more blogposts on the page.

```
<section class="bg-grey" id="category">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="main col-md-12" id="category">
                <div id="posts"></div>
                <p id="loading" class="text-center">
                    <img src="/images/bx_loader.gif" alt="Loading…" />
                </p>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

jquery code here:

```
var start_index = 0;
var products_to_show = 6;

var win = $(window);
win.scroll(function() {

    if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {

        $('#loading').show();

        if(start_index < max_items){

            var datax = {
                'start_index' : start_index
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax-includes/get-post.php',
                data:datax,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(html) {
                    $(html).hide().fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#posts');
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            });
            start_index = start_index + products_to_show;
        }else{
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

here is the code for getpost.php

```
<div class="item col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 scroll">
    <div class="product">
        load blogstuff here
    </div>
</div>
```

When i scroll to the bottom the code triggers fine, but only on desktop (bigger screens), on phone i need to scroll to the bottom before this trigger, is there a way to make this trigger on a spesific div?
So when div is visable do the same thing, or if anyone have a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know position of your `div` then you can do it like:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   var divTop = $('#id of your div').offset().top;
   var divHeight = $('#id of your div').height();
   var winHeight = $(window).height();
   if (fromTop <= divTop && (divTop + divHeight  - winHeight) <= 0) {
      // your div is visible
      // here goes your code
   }
});
```

Comment: i know the id or classname

Comment: I edited answer. If you provide id for div I will correct answer

Comment: i need my code aboue as well: if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) { is there a way to edit this instead?

Comment: I see, but this line doesn't work as expected. I edited again

Comment: Iv tested the code and added my classname, cant relly say it triggers, tested with a simple alert but i get nothing out. #id of your div is the same on both?

Comment: Yes, the same. But if you add classname and only one element it has, then instead of `$('#id of your div')` you can write `$('.classname')`. I guess you see that instead of classname you need to write real classname you use

Comment: Could you provide your code with ids or classname, as it is ?

Comment: I'm from mobile phpne) no possibility to run code. thx for the full example! At first sight it looks like the problem place in the condition `$(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()`. Very strict == test, seems to me. Cause of some events with actual values might be skipped by event system of browser, especially when fast scrolling occurs. Here would be better to use soft conditions, like >= with calculated range for turn on or off visibility. And this place `$(html).hide().fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#posts');` looks redundant. While el not appended to page it is not visible.

Comment: No, about second thing I'm wrong. Didn't notice appending at the end of line ) all ok

Comment: allright, this code represent a smoothscroll function on a blog, when i scroll to a spesific div under the blogs, im adding more content using ajax, i need to make it trigger on a div, but the code aboue dossent seam to work.